# A question about a practice problem

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

Youtube has been helping me get used to working with sets and functions lately, and I've been following the lectures of Mathoma who has created an astounding set-theory playlist that goes through the elementary basics every student must be accustomed to. Now while discussing functions I found this practice problem:

> Show that if $F$ is an injective function, that $F^{-1}$ is a function.

The first one requires us to prove the existence of the inverse function of $f$ using the premise stating that it is injective. I found this impossible for I have been taught that it must be true that a function must be both injective and surjective in order to have an inverse function. Perhaps, I said, instead of $f^{-1}$ what was meant to be written was 'left-inverse'?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct that for $f:A\to B$ to have an inverse $f^{-1}:B\to A$ that $f$ would need to be bijective.  They might be intending to ask instead about $f^{-1}:\text{range}(f)\to A$, that is where we restrict the domain of $f^{-1}$ to just the range of $f$ instead... which is trivially surjective by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $F:A \to B$ where $F$ is an injective function.  Let $C$ denote the subset of $B$ represented by $F(A)$.  That is, $C$ denotes the set that contains every element $c$ in $B$ such that there exists an element $a \in A$, where $F(a) = c.$

Then $F:A \to C$ is injective and surjective, and so there exists an inverse function $F^{-1}:C \to A$.

I suspect that that is the intended idea.

Comment: So the idea inteded it to restrict the function $f^-1$ to $ran(f)$? Which would be $f^-1|ran(f)$; This is what you are saying, correct?

Comment: @Camelot823 Yes, that's it.  The domain of $F^{-1}$ is restricted to the range of $F$.

Comment: Thank you much, user2661923

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from [this video](https://youtu.be/C-2QFE9zsPU).  Here, $\ F^{-1}\ $ denotes the inverse of the *relation* $\ F\ $, not necessarily of that the function $\ F\ $ for which some codomain has been specified.

The video gives the standard set theoretic definitions of relations and functions, a relation being a set of ordered pairs and a function being a special sort of relation—namely a relation $\ F\ $ such that $\ xFy_1\ \&\ $$xFy_2\Rightarrow$$\,y_1=y_2\ $.  *All* relations have an inverse, defined in the segment from $9$:$19$ to $9$:$45$ of the video by
$$
F^{-1}=\big\{\,\langle x,y\rangle\,
\big|\, yFx\ \big\}\ .
$$
What the exercise is asking you to do is prove that if $\ F\ $ is an injective function then the *relation* $\ F^{-1}\ $ is a function—that is that
$$
xF^{-1}y_1\,\&\,xF^{-1}y_2\,\Rightarrow\,y_1=y_2\ .
$$
The proof is pretty much a trivial one-liner.

If $\ F:B\rightarrow A\ $ is a function mapping $\ B\ $ into $\ A\ $, then the *relation* $\ F^{-1}\ $ (which *always* exists) isn't necessarily an inverse for that function, however.  For this to be true, $\ F^{-1}\ $ must be a *function* with domain $\ A\ $. It will be a function if and only if $\ F\ $ is injective, and it's domain will be $\ A\ $ if and only if $\ A\ $ is the *range* of $\ F\ $—that is, if and only if $\ F\ $ is surjective.  Nothing in the statement of the practice problem, nor in the rest of the video, as far as I can tell, contradicts this.